# Sync Picture/Sound over HDMI on iMac in Protools: How to check?

Tags: sync, imac

Hi,

I was wondering if there are any other solutions to checking sync in PT9 than Syncheck3.
It's quite expensive and hope there is another way to do it.

Arnoud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find someone local with a Sync Checker & pay them to check it for you:

http://www.pharoahaudio.com/syncheckproducthomepage.html

It is a device with a microphone and light sensor built in, so it 'hears' the 2pop and 'sees' the flash frame - when you play a QT it can verify sync within 1/100th of a frame!

More info and results from some of their tests with ProTools configs here:

http://www.pharoahaudio.com/ptvideosyncstudy.html

http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/calibration-2-sync

Comment: Thanks Tim! I already knew about the device, but renting might be better than buying indeed. And from your own blog: "Remember if you are using an Plasma, LCD TV or 100 HZ widescreen CRT TV set as a monitor you WILL have a delay induced by the latency inherent in these devices. This will delay the picture you are viewing by up to 2 or 3 frames!  That explains the sync issue with my new setup :)

Answer (score 1):

I do it by eye with a 2 pip. I rationalise this by saying that we are the ones to whom sync matters (as in humans, as opposed to machines), so if a pip looks like it's in sync, then that's good enough.

One of the problems with this is our brain's tendency to try to sync things up after the fact. I've found that looking away from the screen, so you can only see the 2 (or flash) out of the corner of your eye, helps avoid the psychological issues with perceiving sync.

I know it's a pretty cheap and dirty solution - but hey, it's worked so far!

Comment: Ha, quick and dirty, but i'll try! Thanks